# Able to get round that Static method PageFactory.InitElements so that I am able to run my tests one after another

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking for some advice.

**Does anyone know how I would be able to get round that Static method PageFactory.InitElements so that I am able to run my tests one after another?**

**Background**

When I attempt to run my selenium webdriver classes one after another using MSunit. I'm getting the following error.

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:7055

I know that if I were to remove the static from all of the classes (based on this question I asked previously:- [Attempting to run multiple Selenium Webdriver tests using Nunit fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28539625/attempting-to-run-multiple-selenium-webdriver-tests-using-nunit-fails), that the tests would run, however the structure of my Automation Framework needs these statics.

From further investigation I found out that `PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, currentIncidentsPage);` that it takes in a Static method.

The way my Automation Framework is set out is as follows

E2ETest

- RegressionTestsFolder

  - AboutsUsTests.cs
- TestFramework

  - PageObjectsFolder

    - AboutUsPage.cs
    - HomePage.cs
  - Browser.cs

AboutUsTests Class

```
public class AboutUsTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Go_To_About_Us_Page_Link_Test()
    {
        Pages.HomePage.Goto();
        Pages.HomePage.SelectAboutLink();
        Assert.IsTrue(Pages.AboutUsPage.IsAt());
    }
}
```

Pages Class

```
public static class Pages
{

    public static HomePage HomePage
    {
        get
        {

            var homePage = new HomePage();
            PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, homePage);
            return homePage;
        }
    }

    public static AboutUsPage AboutUsPage
    {
        get
        {
            var aboutUsPage = new AboutUsPage();
            PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, aboutUsPage);
            return aboutUsPage;
        }
    }
}
```

Browser Class

```
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;

    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

    public static class Browser
    {

        private static readonly IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();

        public static ISearchContext Driver
        {
            get
            {
                return webDriver;
            }
        }


        public static string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return webDriver.Title;
            }
        }



        public static void Goto(string url)
        {
            webDriver.Url = url;
        }



        public static void Close()
        {
            webDriver.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

HomePage Class

```
public class HomePage
    {

        private static readonly string Url = "http://myurl.com";

        private static readonly string PageTitle = "My title page";


        [FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "[href*='/about/']")]
        private IWebElement aboutUsLinkElement;



        public void Goto()
        {
            Browser.Goto(Url);
            Browser.BrowserMax();
        }


        public bool IsAt()
        {
            return Browser.Title == PageTitle;
        }



        public void SelectAboutLink()
        {
            this.aboutUsLinkElement.Click();
        }


    }
}
```

AboutUsPage Class

```
namespace TestFramework.PageObjects
{
    using System;

    using TestFramework.Interfaces;

    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;


    public class AboutUsPage
    {

        private static readonly string PageTitle = "About Us";

        public bool IsAt()
        {
            return Browser.Title == PageTitle;
        }

    }
}
```

Any help would be gratefully apprenticed, as I have been going round in circles trying to figure this out.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using nunit framework too? What is your testrunner?

Comment: https://github.com/AlexMoll91/SeleniumExample if you want a reference of an example using pagefactory and running with nunit.

Comment: I'm using MSunit as my test runner at present,

Comment: Nunit 3.0 and the extension will help I think. Then you can unlock the [test] and [testfixture] attributes.

Comment: I found a solution to my issue, looking at the framework from the following GitHub repo :- https://github.com/PaulSodimu/PageObjectPattern I figured out a solution to my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get a similar error but for a different reason, in my case it is because I have a logout method in my Cleanup class and for some reason is not OK. If I remove the logout from my cleanup and use only driver.Quit();  it works OK with no errors. This is what I use :

1. I have a class for the driver - this is in the main framework, like your Browser:

   ```
   public class Utils
   {
       public static IWebDriver driver { get; set; }
       ....
   }
   ```
2. I have a class  TestUtil.cs at the tests level:

   ```
   public static IWebDriver GetDriver()
   {
       string driverName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["driver"];
       switch(driverName)
       {
           case "Chrome":
           Utils.driver = new ChromeDriver();
           break;

           case "Firefox":
           Utils.driver = new FirefoxDriver();
           break;
       }
      return Utils.driver;
   }
   ```
3. In my tests I use this :

   ```
   [TestClass]
   public class HomePageTests
   {

       public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }


       [ClassInitialize]
       public static void Initialize(TestContext context)
       {
           if (Utils.driver != null)
               Utils.driver.Quit();

           Utils.driver = TestUtils.GetDriver();
           Utils.driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
       }
   }
   ```

In this way I only have that error in the console when I use logout in the cleanup class but so far this doesn't block the tests from running.

In my page class I have this :

```
public  class HomePage
{

    public HomePage()
    {
        PageFactory.InitElements(Utils.driver, this);
    }
```

Sorry for crappy formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ami2110, I found a solution to my issue here:- https://github.com/PaulSodimu/PageObjectPattern, however I believe your solution is a good solution as well. I hope the link I've shared might help you with your logout issue

Comment: Thank you for the link, I already use the cleanup in that way , containing only driver.Quit(); and it works fine. I thought I'll encounter session mix problems because I don't do a logout but it seems the webdriver is smart enough to start a clean new session every time so I don't necessarily need the logout in the cleanup class. However, the link you provided has a lot of useful code that I could use, thanks for sharing.